# Golang pointer string to value

Tags: pointers, go, flags

Some code I am using flags for managing the program or service. Today I got the problem, where I wanted to use this kind of declaration:

```
var port = flag.String("port", "", "port")
```

It is return back a `*string` type variable what I can't convert to `string`. 
How I managed the problem:

```
r.Run(":" + *port)
```

It is working but what is the best practice for that? I mean there are loads of function which is waiting string as parameter, and in this case I can't handle that.

Comment: Anything returned by the `flag` package functions is a pointer, since it needs to be modified "behind the scenes". You're probably better off using a `flag.Int`, though, since you're currently open for someone to call your program with "-flag crashy", which will most likely cause a panic.

Comment: Well, then use `flag.StringVar`. Sometimes reading the package documentation really does help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `port` variable is of type `*string` (this is what [`flag.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#String) returns). To get a value of type `string`, there's no other way than to dereference it: `*port`.

You may do so at every place where you need to pass it as a `string`, or you may use [`flag.StringVar()`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#StringVar) instead:

```
var port string

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&port, "port", "", "port")
}
```

In this case, your `port` variable is of type `string`, so no dereferencing is needed. Here you explicitly provide a `*string` value to the `flag` package to be used: the address of your variable of type `string`, which will be of type `*string` of course (so the `flag` package will be able to modify / set the pointed value). The `flag.String()` is a convenience function which allocates a `string` value and returns you the pointer to it.

Another option would be to dereference it once and store the `string` value in another variable of type `string`, for example:

```
var portp = flag.String("port", "", "port")
var port string

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    port = *portp
    // Now you can use port which is of type string
}
```

But I prefer the `flag.StringVar()` solution.

Note that however a port is a number, you may be better off using [`flag.Int()`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Int) or [`flag.IntVar()`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#IntVar):

```
var port int

func init() {
    flag.IntVar(&port, "port", 0, "port")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use it as is or just convert it to a string.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "flag"

func main () {

    var port = flag.String("port", "", "port")
    flag.Parse()

    test(*port)

    newstring := *port

    test(newstring)
}

func test (s string) {

    fmt.Println(s)

}
```